# A Template for absolute path on the server

Tags: spring, logging, jboss, centos

I would track a log file of an App deployed on the server. I use SPRING for my app (WAR file) and Server is WILDFLY 8. VM is CENTOS 7. 
For testing my app on my local machine in application.properties I just write

```
logging.path = /home/username/folder
```

and that's it, but how can I apply the same to the server? Have I use a follows pattern?

logging.path=[dns:port]/~/folder

or maybe another one? Appreciate your help!

Comment: Do you want to set logging path for Wildfly ?

Comment: I believe, i can use the same Template quasi, /root/... The problem is, that in deployments an app was with suffix .deployed, but actually it wasn't deployed proper. I haven't solved the problem yet, but I suppose, it will works or? Have to be set any special permissions for app to write on server (makes new files and so on)? I believe not...